# What type of jquery animation is this?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, append, jquery-effects

Hi I found a cool animation on this [website](http://teespring.com):

On the middle of the page (right side) there is a review section that the texts are shown in a cool manner. I want to add that kind of effect on my project I am building now but I am not familiar with the effect type and the algorithm itself. Does anyone knows it and how to code such thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You just have two divs with different speed of animation, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$('.one').animate({top:100}, 500);
$('.two').animate({top:200}, 1000);
```

That's it, you need to set the proper `top` of course based on the height of the divs (get that dynamically).

Comment: Hello, does the .animate() function fades in and out?

Comment: No, you need to chain that with `.fadeIn(time in ms)` and `.fadeOut(time in ms)`.